# Weird error when running my SFML game?

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2015, 2d, sfml

So, I'm making a game using SFML in C++, but when I tried adding a image a really weird OpenGL(i think) error popped up. Doesn't make any sense at all.
First my console was spammed with random text and symbols, then the application crashed and visual studio told me this :

```
Exception thrown at 0x618EDBF4 (vcruntime140.dll) in SFML_Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00C54000.
```

It sounds like it has something to do with not being able to read my picture file I added, though i don't know whats wring with it.
The location of the image is in the same folder my **"SFML_Game.vcxproj"** is.

I also have no chance of seeing if "Could not load player image" was printed in console since the spam is too quick.

**Edit** I can see that the picture failed to load now, here's a picture... :

[Console Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZobz.png)

Here's my current code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Creates a window
    sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Game Engine");

    sf::Texture pTexture;
    sf::Sprite playerImage;

    if (!pTexture.loadFromFile("Player.png"))
    {
        std::cout << "Could not load player image" << std::endl;
    }

    playerImage.setTexture(pTexture);

    while (Window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event Event;
        while (Window.pollEvent(Event) && Window.hasFocus())
        {
            switch (Event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                Window.close();
                break;
            }
        }


        Window.draw(playerImage);
        Window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: You tested if the texture can't be loaded but continued as it worked... You should handle that error in a better way.

Comment: The location of the file should be the application's *working directory*. By default, VS sets that to the directory where the resulting .exe is. You can set it in the project's options, under "Debug".

Comment: @molbdnilo Added it to the Debug folder where the exe is,. it still fails to load the image for some reason.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, it seems that my code was fine and it was a linker error.
I didn't know the difference between static-dynamic, static and dynamic libraries, so I just put them all in there, after removing some of them it started working.
At least in debugging mode.

Pretty much, if someone else has this problem, look up how to set SFML up on their website instead of a video tutorial. ^^